# Check if element support the property using jquery

Tags: jquery

Jquery newbie here.

In a wrapped element set, is there a way to check if the element supports this property?

I basically have this pseudocode.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").each(function(){
        if("this element supports disabled"){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

I was thinking that if the element does not support this property then it should be skipped.

In my example above, I was checking if the element supports the disabled attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really isn't possible to tell because you can set an attribute on an element even if it doesn't support it. As far as I know, only form elements support the `disabled` property, so you can just check if the element is of type `input`, `select`, `textarea` or `button`. (there may be a few more that I missed)

Comment: Other elements are `option` and `optgroup` - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1